# Python - Iteration Testing a SOAP service; need to use different variables per iteration

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, iteration

Ok here's my scenario (be kind, only been using Python for a short while):

I have a service I'm calling and need to run several iterations of the same test with a different variable passed to the method.  I am able to run iterations against a single method just fine but I need the variable to change per each test and without counting the call to get a random variable as an iteration.  I'm probably going about this the wrong way but I'd love any help I can get.

Here's my code thus far:

```
data = ""

class MyTestWorkFlow:
    global data 
    def Data(self):
        low = 1
        high = 1000
        pid = random.randrange(low,high)
        data = linecache.getline('c:/tmp/testData.csv', pid)

    def Run(self):
        client = Client(wsdl)
        result = client.service.LookupData(data)
        f = open('/tmp/content','w')
        f.write (str(result))
        f.close()
        f = open('/tmp/content','r')
        for i in f:
            print i
        f.close()

test = MyTestWorkFlow()
for i in range(1,2):
  test.Run()
```

Comment: Little tip: do not use global: you can simply assign `self.data = something` and then use in another method with, for example, `result = client.service.LookupData(self.data)`

Comment: Which variable do you need to change?

Comment: the variable data is getting a random variable from a csv file.  i need that method to be ran each time i do an iteration of Run and the data variable in the method Run needs to be updated so I get a broader range of results.

Comment: I managed to work around using global but I still have to define data out side of my classes otherwise I'll get the following error:
NameError: global name 'data' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot we could talk about regarding automated testing in Python, but the problem here is that you don't seem to be invoking your `Data` method.

If you change your code like this:

```
def Run(self)
    self.Data()
    client = Client(wsdl)
    ...
```

does it do what you need?

Comment: It makes a lot of sense, however, it doesn't change my output.  Looks like I'm getting my test data just fine but I'm always getting the same test data... as if it is cached somehow.